# Reading a sound file from the disk with Overtone?

Tags: clojure, supercollider, overtone

I would like to use Overtone to play a longer continuous audio file from disk.

I know Overtone has [facilities for loading in *samples* into memory](https://github.com/overtone/overtone/wiki/Buffers-and-audio-files), but seeing as these files will be long and large (possibly on the order of hours), this is not the method I want to use.

SuperCollider - which Overtone uses as its audio engine - however, also has another way to load and stream files, namely [using DiskIn](http://danielnouri.org/docs/SuperColliderHelp/UGens/Playback%20and%20Recording/DiskIn.html), which [Overtone also seems to have](http://overtone-docs.herokuapp.com/overtone/overtone.core/disk-in), but I wasn't able to find ([docs](http://overtone-docs.herokuapp.com/search?x=0&y=0&q=cueSoundFile&lib=overtone), [github](https://github.com/overtone/overtone/search?q=cuesoundfile&unscoped_q=cuesoundfile)) a corresponding `Buffer.cueSoundFile()` function.

Does Overtone have `cueSoundFile` at all? Is there another way I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cueSoundFile is a fancier term for the equivalent osc message /b_read which you'll find in Overtone as `overtone.sc.buffer/buffer-cue`.

As a 5 second demo, this plays a 2-channel file from disk.

```
(demo (disk-in 2 (buffer-cue "~/Music/10mb.wav")))
```

And the doc for disk-in (SC DiskIn)

```
user=> (doc disk-in)
-------------------------
overtone.live/disk-in
([numChannels bufnum loop])

  stream audio in from disk file

  [numChannels :none, bufnum :none, loop 0]

  numChannels - Number of channels in the incoming
                audio.
  bufnum      - Id of buffer
  loop        - Soundfile will loop if 1 otherwise
                not.

  Continuously play a longer soundfile from disk. This
  requires a buffer to be preloaded with one buffer size of
  sound. If loop is set to 1, the soundfile will loop.

  Categories: InOut, Buffer
  Rates: [ :ar ]
  Default rate: :ar
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! A tiny follow up question, how would I know this? Is it just familiarity with SC? Overtone's documentation is fairly lacking :/